# How to Fix IntelliJ IDEA Package Name on Mac

Tags: java, macos, github, intellij-idea, package

## How to Fix IntelliJ IDEA Package Name

### MacOS Mojave 10.14.1 | Java 11.0.1 | IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 (CE)

I have a project on GitHub, *[swift-for-java](https://github.com/Wildchild9/swift-for-java)*, that contains the contents of the folder *SwiftFramework*.

**Problem:**
All of the files within the folder *Swift* say `package SwiftFramework.Swift;` at the top. My problem is, that when someone downloads it off of GitHub (per the installation instructions provided), an issue arises because all the package names are `SwiftFramework.Swift` when now they should all be just `Swift`.

I am trying to find a way to fix this without manually replacing every occurrence of `SwiftFramework.Swift` with `Swift` before every single commit. My git repository exists inside the folder *SwiftFramework*, outlined in the red box in the image below.

[image: SwiftFramework - IntelliJ Idea]

**Note:** Also, any suggestions for a better way to do this (i.e. putting it in a different project, changing my GitHub installation/usage instructions, etc.) are welcome and would be greatly appreciated as this is my first time doing something of this nature.

Comment: Move every class package under `Swift` to `SwiftFramework`, then rename the base package to `Swift`

Comment: My only problem with that @PeterLawrey is that I want all of the actual framework files to be under their own folder, for the ease of the user to import it into their own project. The same problem will then exist because then the files won't be under `Swift` anymore, they won't be under anything, that's why I have a folder inside of a folder, please check the GitHub link provided.